# Not able to run headless even after setting everything

Tags: selenium-webdriver, headless, brave

I am trying to run my code in headless mode (*it runs fine without headless*). I have tried almost every option given on the internet.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from fake_headers import Headers

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/snap/brave/current/opt/brave.com/brave/brave'
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/home/dhruv/snap/brave/current/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--disable-xss-auditor")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1366,768")
options.add_argument("-disable-gpu")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
user_agent = Headers(
    browser="chrome", os="lin", headers=False
).generate()['User-Agent']
# user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5845.180 Safari/537.36'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
# user_agent = 'MQQBrowser/26 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.7; zh-cn; MB200 Build/GRJ22; CyanogenMod-7) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent="{user_agent}"')

driver_path = '/home/dhruv/Downloads/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver'
service = Service(executable_path=driver_path, log_path = '/home/dhruv/python/chromedriver.log')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, service = service)

try :
    driver.get("brave://settings/appearance")
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")

    elm = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "settings-ui").shadow_root\
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "settings-main").shadow_root\
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "settings-basic-page").shadow_root\
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[section=appearance] settings-appearance-page").shadow_root\
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "settings-animated-pages settings-brave-appearance-theme").shadow_root\
            .find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#braveThemeType")
    select = Select(elm)
    if select.first_selected_option.get_attribute("value") == "1":
        select.select_by_value("2")
    else:
        select.select_by_value("1")
finally :
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

I still get the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"settings-ui"}
>
> (Session info: headless chrome=116.1.57.62); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

In the second line of the error it says session is `headless chrome=116.1.57.62`. What should I do now? Totally exhausted on the options.

I am using Brave browser, selenium version 4.11.2, chromium version 116.0.5845.180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to latest update the new way of using headless worked for me. Specify `--headless=new` instead of `--headless`.